# Path does not exist during CICD with code magic

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, cicd, codemagic

when i am running this command it gives this error

**Command:**

```
 - name: Build ipa for distribution
  script: | 
  xcode-project build-ipa \
  --workspace "$CM_BUILD_DIR/ios/$XCODE_WORKSPACE" \
  --scheme "$XCODE_SCHEME"
```

**Error Snapshot**

```
xcode-project: error: argument --export-options-plist: Path "/Users/builder/export_options.plist" does not exist


Build failed :|
Step 6 script `Build ipa for distribution` exited with status code 2
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Need to add `xcode-project use-profiles` step before building the IPA. Error seems to be missing code signing step.

```
- name: Install CocoaPods dependencies
  script: | 
     cd ios && pod install
- name: Set up provisioning profiles settings on Xcode project
  script: xcode-project use-profiles
- name: Build ipa for distribution
  script: | 
     xcode-project build-ipa \
     --workspace "$CM_BUILD_DIR/ios/$XCODE_WORKSPACE" \
     --scheme "$XCODE_SCHEME"
```

Reference:
https://docs.codemagic.io/yaml-code-signing/signing-ios/